# Is there any parts repository available for blender?

Tags: units

In autodesk, sketchup there are some specific parts repository to import directly.
Is there this kind of repository for blender?

Comment: What kind of parts? Have you tried searching on Google? Nothing came up?

Comment: For example transformers, power tower, generators, pipe plumbing fittings etc. I can find some by google but it is dispersed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender uses addons (like plugins) to extend its resources and tools. These are found in File>User Preferences.

[image: Addons extras]

Blender comes packaged with Extra Curve objects and Extra Mesh objects addons. But you have to activate them first in the User Prefs panel as shown above.

[image: Extra curves]

[image: Extra mesh]

Comment: Thank you so much. I find the place to go through the add-ons of blender:   http://wiki.blender.org

Comment: I am glad to help. If the answer is suitable, please accept with the tick ;-)